# Segmentation fault (core dumped) in C Unix

Tags: c, multithreading, unix

I have to create a program that gets from the command line n arguments arg1, arg2 .... argn, creates n threads and each of them will read a text file argi and will print in reverse order even lines.

The problem is that my program creates the threads, finishes them, but actually he does nothing. He prints only some random characters, different at every runtime(characters from memory i think).

Below is my code:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAXLINE 100
pthread_t myThread[10];
pthread_mutex_t myMutex;

void * fileprint(void * numei) {
    printf("Thread: %ld ...> %s\n", pthread_self(), (char*)numei);
    FILE *fi;
    char line[MAXLINE], *p;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&myMutex);
    int k=0;
    fi = fopen((char*)numei, "r");
    for ( ; ; ) {
        k++;
        p = fgets(line, MAXLINE, fi);
        if (p == NULL) break;
        line[strlen(line) - 1] = '\0';
        if(k %2 ==0){
            for(int j=strlen(line);j>=0;j++){
                printf("%c", line[j]);
            }
        printf("%c","\n");
        }
    }

    fclose(fi);

    printf("Finished thread: %ld ...> %s\n", pthread_self(), (char*)numei);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&myMutex); 

}


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    pthread_mutex_init(&myMutex, NULL); 
    printf("I'm the father...\n");  

    int i;
    for (i = 1; argv[i]; i++) {
        pthread_create(&myThread[i], NULL, fileprint, (void*)argv[i]);
        printf("Created thread: %ld ...> %s\n", myThread[i], argv[i]);
    }


    for (i = 1; argv[i]; i++) {
        pthread_join(myThread[i], NULL);    
    }

    printf("I'm still the father...\n");


    pthread_mutex_destroy(&myMutex);

    return 1;
}
```

So, anyone can tell me what's the problem? I tried lots of things to modify but nothing...

Comment: Have you tried running in a debugger? It will stop at the location of the crash and let you examine (and walk) the function call stack as well as let you examine variables and their values.

Comment: Oh, and you have an off-by-one error in the inner loop, when you start by printing out the terminating `'\0'` character in the line you read.

Comment: You might also want to think about what would happen if `fopen` fails.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about having someone else think for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you walk the string backward, you have to decrement the index inside the loop (`j--`). Also you should start at `strlen(x)-1`.

Comment: Good catch. With the increment, he's trying to print all of memory starting at the end of the string.

Comment: no way.... this was the problem... and i changed, added, deleted around 100 lines... but i missed that:| Thx!

Answer (score 3):

This line is incorrect:

```
printf("%c","\n");
```

The operand of `%c` must be a `char`, not `char*`. It should be either:

```
printf("%c",'\n');
```

or:

```
printf("%s", "\n");
```

or:

```
printf("\n");
```

However, I don't think this will cause a segmentation fault, it will just cause a random character to be printed.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i = 1; argv[i]; i++) {
```

You can also use "argc", it's the arg-counter.

```
 printf("Thread: %ld ...> %s\n", pthread_self(), (char*)numei);
FILE *fi;
char line[MAXLINE], *p;
pthread_mutex_lock(&myMutex);
```

In your fileprint(...), put the printf(...) behind the mutex, or other threads could interrupt it and you get half-printed, weird sentences on you output.

mfg